# Hardware bluetooth doesn't activate when hardware switch is on

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop, windows-8.1, bluetooth

my laptop is a Toshiba Satellite c55-b5200. 
I upgraded from a 2.4ghz only wifi card (m.2 NGFF) to an Intel 8620NGW.

The integrated Bluetooth on the card isn't recognized, and doesn't show up in device manager or any other devices/connected hardware menu.

All the correct drivers are installed and I have cross-checked all sources for help. I've even tried to tape pins, **54** and **56** to disable the hardware shutoff from the m.2 port.

This made no difference and I'm still stuck. Ever since I upgraded to windows 10 my hardware button (fn+f12) only turns wifi on and off.

When using **Windows 8/8.1** with identical hardware, it would alternate turning **Bluetooth** AND **WiFi** on and off.

I don't know how to fix this and I think this may be the reason why Bluetooth is off. I remember turning Bluetooth off in windows 8.1 before updating to windows 10 and I'm wondering if there could have been any leftover memory in either the bios or some sort of hardware controller that is keeping it off and I'm unable to turn it on due to my broken hardware key combo.

Is there any way to fix this, or will I have to backtrack to windows 8.1, turn on Bluetooth and come back to windows 10. I remember having to do this one time for another reason on another laptop (Acer aspire v3 for a sound driver where the audio jack wouldn't work with an inline mic).

I don't know if I'm asking in the right place so if I am not please let me know and I will remove my post and ask in the right place.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart no it doesn't appear under Bluetooth devices. It would do the same under Windows 8.1 where it would assume the hardware was removed from the computer altogether when I switched it off.

Comment: Device manager > action menu > add legacy device > choose the device yourself > find your Intel card in the list. (It will Only show up if the drivers were installed correctly) lemme know if that works for you

Comment: @Tim_Stewart No sir, I tried to do that but it shows up as Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 #2 and comes up with error code 31 saying "this device is not working properly because the right driver cannot be loaded for this device". Unfortunately nothing shows up under Bluetooth as well.